# How should I stack these folded dipoles?

Tags: vhf, antenna-system, dipole, phased-array, folded-dipole

Looking to stack these 8 folded dipoles on my 100ft tower.

I can not find any information whatsoever on these. I have 4 consecutive serial numbered boxes.

> Bluewave Marathon
>   BME139FN1H0
>   138 - 174 MHz
>   Gain  5.5dBd

Looking for information on an appropriate phasing harness and spacing.

[image: Photo of antenna in packaging]

Comment: What is the actual goal of this? And is it 8 individual folded dipoles, or 8 pairs like the photo?

Comment: 4 boxes, 4 pairs, for a total of 8 individual folded dipoles. Can configure 4 TX and 4 RX or stack all 8 and use a Sinclair duplexer.

Comment: The end goal is a DMR repeater in the middle between Calgary and Edmonton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info is in the model number

BM - Bluewave Marathon
E  - Exposed offset
139- Frequency
F  - Gain 5.5dBd
N1 - Connector Type
H  - Horizontal Polarized

[More info can be found here](https://www.scribd.com/document/31276153/Yagi-From-Pctel) - Please note you may have to download the whole book for all info.